# How to use Cudnn LSTM instead of a normal LSTM

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm

I have been working on a named entity recognition task. I have the following piece of code in between

```
with tf.variable_scope("Bi-lstm"):
        cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_size)
        cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_size)
        (output_fw, output_bw), _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, 
            cell_bw, self.word_embeddings, sequence_length=self.sequence_lengths, 
            dtype=tf.float32)
```

Now I want to use a Cudnn LSTM instead of the normal LSTM. In the documentation of Cudnn LSTM, there is an additional argument "num_layers". I did not understand what this is and how I have to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version if TF you are you are using, but in the TF 2.0 documentation, you need to use:

```
tf.keras.layers.LSTM
```

instead of:

```
tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn#using_cudnn_kernels_when_available